# Existence of a limit does not imply differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to show that if the limit(in the definition of the derivative for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m$)  exists, then we do not necessarily have differentiability.

My try: Consider $f : \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$. Let $x_0 = (0,0)$. Then

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - T(h)}{||h||} = 0 \iff T(x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{||h||}$$

Put $h = tx$. Then, $h \to 0 \iff t \to 0$. Hence

$$ T(x,y) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t \sqrt{|xy|}}{t ||x||} = \frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Then, we have a contradiction since $T$ is not linear. Hence, it cannot be differentiable at $x_0 = 0$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm  not exactly sure what you are trying to prove. That is, if a continuous, linear $T$ exists such that the limit in the question is zero, then $T$ **must** be the derivative of $f$ at that point.

By looking at $f(x,x) = |x|$, it is clear that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ (the limits from $ x<0$ and $x>0$ are $-1$ and $+1$ respectively).

Hence if you assume such a continuous, linear $T$ exists, then a contradiction **must** arise.

Comment: I am trying to prove that $f$ is not differentiable at the origin. I assumed by conrtradiction that it is differentiable: there exists a $T$ that satisfies the above. Then, I obtained a contradiction. Is it correct my approach?

Comment: Your approach works.