# Does existence of limit $x\to 0$ of derivative imply function is differentiable at 0?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

> Suppose $f\in C(\mathbb R)\cap C^1(\mathbb R\setminus \{ 0\})$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x) $ exists and equals $L\in\mathbb R$ . Does this imply that $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$?

Derivatives cannot have jump singularities, since they satisfy the intermediate value property. Therefore, if $f'(0)$ exists, its value must be $L$, and $f$ is then $C^1$. But this doesn't prove the result.

I also can't imagine a counterexample...

Remarks:

1. This seems simple enough that it should have been asked before, but I can't find a duplicate. Moreover, (see rem. 3) its not so unnatural to assume its true. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285914/f-differentiable-at-0-iff-lim-x-to-0-fracf2x-fxx-exists) is kind of close. Most questions with similar names seem to be about [multivariate calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695959/existence-of-a-limit-does-not-imply-differentiability).
2. Note the standard example of a function whose derivative is not continuous at 0 does not help ($f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$)
3. If true, this result would validate attempts to prove the differentiability of e.g. $e^{-1/|x|}$  by establishing the existence of the above limit instead.

Comment: It's a standard result proved via mean value theorem. If $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $a$ and $\lim_{x\to a} f'(x) =L$ then $f'(a) $ exists and is equal to $L$. Use the fact that $$\frac{f(x) - f(a)} {x-a} =f'(c) $$ and as $x\to a$ we have $c\to a$. Since RHS tends to $L$ so does LHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By l'Hopital's rule you have that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} f'(x) = L,
$$
hence $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0) = L$.
We can then conclude that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Oh! that's nice...